# Eclipse - Running an Android app that runs on other machines' Eclipses, won't run in my Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've spent hours trying to figure out what the problem could be. As I said the code runs fine on the Android emulators on other machines' Eclipses, but in my Eclipse it won't run. It compiles fine, but when I run it, Logcat shows me a bunch of errors, many of them being NoClassDefFoundError's for classes that I have right in my Eclipse (and which were able to be complied). Does anyone have any insight as to what might be the case that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Are they in the same project? Is your buildpath set up correctly? If so, maybe try project > clean, which seems to solve some weird errors with Android and eclipse

Comment: Tim, are you trying to use an AVD on your machine that doesn't include, say the Google Maps library? It may compile fine on your machine, but if the AVD (emulator) you are using doesn't have the Google API's added to it's configuration, you could get those errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the libraries referenced by the NoClassDefFoundError's are missing.

You should try to figure out where those should be--or where they are located on other peoples systems, make sure they are at the same location on your system and then ensure they are in your build path.

Comment: I don't get it though. Would it still compile if this were the case? I will look into this though, thank you.

Comment: The runtime path can be different from the compile path--make sure that your runtime classpath is correct.  You might consider creating a new workspace, checking out the code again and see what happens.  It's a reasonable goal to say that this process should not be difficult--so this gives you a chance to assert that as well :)

Comment: Whoa, how do you change the compile path differently from the runtime classpath? All I know how to do is configure buildpath for a project.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your references, especially under the Android tab.  By default Android references aren't exported, so if A depends on B, which in turn depends on C, A has to include C in it's libraries, otherwise C won't get included (causing NoClassDefFoundError's)